# Evolution of a closed set under a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I consider an ordinary differential equation

$$
\dot x = f(x), \quad x(0) = x_0 \in X_0 \subset \mathbb R^n. \quad (*)
$$

Let $f$ allow for a unique solution on $X_0$ and on the whole time interval and let $\Phi$ be the evolution operator defined through $x(t) = \Phi(t)x_0$, where $x$ is the solution of $(*)$.

From stability theory (namely the *continuous dependence of the solution on the initial value*) it is known that if $X_0$ is an open set, then $X_t:=\Phi(t)X_0$ is an open set.

Does it hold that if $X_0$ is a **closed set**, then $X_t:=\Phi(t)X_0$ is **closed**. Furthermore, does it hold that, if $\partial X_0$ is the boundary of $X_0$, then $\Phi(t)\partial X_0$ is the boundary of $X_t$.

Any hint of reference is greatly appreciated.